# How to guarantee existence of a constant?

Tags: calculus

Let $F(x) = \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t)dt$, where $h$ is continuous and $g, f$ are differentiable.

I want to make $$F(x) = \int_{f(x)}^{a} h(t)dt + \int _{a}^{g(x)}h(t)dt$$ and then apply the Fundamental theorem of Calculus. But I don't know how to argue that such $a$ does exists.

Comment: You can choose any $a$ in the (connected) domain of $h$, can you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that $h$ is continuous in some interval $J\subset{\mathbb R}$, and it is tacitly assumed that for all $x$ under consideration $f(x)$, $g(x)\in J$. In such a case for all $a\in J$ and all $x$ one has
$$\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t)\>dt=\int_{f(x)}^a h(t)\>dt+\int_a^{g(x)}h(t)\>dt\ .\tag{1}$$
*Proof.* Since $h$ is continuous on $J$ the function $h$ possesses a primitive $H$ on $J$, and one has, **by definition**,
$$\int_u^v h(t)\>dt=H(v)-H(u)\qquad\forall u,\ v\in J\ ,$$
whether $u<v$, $u=v$, or  $u>v$. This immediately implies $(1)$.$\quad\square$

Comment: But (1) holds if $f(x)<a<g(x)$.

Comment: And that is my confusion, do we have to choose an $a$ for every $x$? How do I know that $f(x)<g(x)$ or what? I'm very confused about that part.

Comment: You have introduced a variable $a$. The formula $(1)$ holds for every value $a\in J$, larger or smaller than $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, or in between the two.

Comment: Now I understand.